# Render show page in Bootstrap modal from index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4 I'm trying to render show.html.erb on my index page inside a bootstrap modal.

`index.html.erb`:

```
<% @links.each do |item| %>

      <h4><%= link_to (item.title), '#myModal', 'data-toggle' => 'modal' %>
        Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %> ago       
      </h4>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="document" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render :partial => 'show_modal', :locals => { :item => item } %>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**_show_modal.html.erb:**

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4" id="telegraph">

<h1><a href="<%= item.url %>" target="_blank"><%= item.title %></a></h1>
  <p><%= item.content %></p>
</div>
```

Currently, the modal is showing nicely, but no matter which link I click, the modal only ever displays the data for the very first `link` inside `@links`

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name each modal differently.

Try setting each modals id to `myModal-id` where `id` is the id of the `item`

For example:

```
   <h4><%= link_to (item.title), "#myModal-#{item.id}", 'data-toggle' => 'modal' %>
   Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %> ago       
   </h4>
```

and

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-<%= item.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="document" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

Comment: I'm Rails noob and I'm trying to do '#myModal-#{title.id}" but it's not working. Guess that's not how to interpolate the id there...

Comment: it would need to be a double quote `"myModal-#{title.id}"`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!
BTW it's item.id rather than title.id